# Transform string to object key value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I'm looking to transform a string that is space separated to an object key value.

**Input**

```
var inputStr = "tab ers cda-de";
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
    tab: true,
    ers: true,
    cda-de: true
}
```

I have underscore and javascript ES6, is there a better way than this:

```
var splitString = inputStr.split(" ");

var obj = {};
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
       obj[item] = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` to create an array from that string, then use `reduce` method to return a object created from the array of string

```js
let str = "tab ers cda-de"

let m = str.split(' ').reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = true
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
"tab ers cda-de".split(' ').reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: true }), {})
```